# Cannot attach Microsoft account. It Just keep signing in. No Error Message and nothing happens even for hours

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-account

I cannot attach Microsoft account in Windows 8.

After I enter my email address, it just keeps waiting. No error message at any point.

Once I just tried for signing up for a new email address from options provided when signing in, this too just kept loading.

I have a fast enough internet connection (3.6 Mbps). Actual downloading speed is 350-400 KBps.

Comment: Any other information / experiments?  Can you create another user with a local account?  Does that account logon?  Are you in a domain (probably not).

Comment: I am an administrator and only user in my windows 8. I tried adding a user using my Microsoft account. The same problem.. just processing and processing.. @GuyThomas

Comment: no sorry! I can add new user using my microsoft account but can't switch to microsoft account